# Usefulness of Cord Reel with 100-ft Extension Cord

Tags: extension-cord

I may be missing something, but how useful is a cord reel such as the one pictured with a 100-ft long extension cord?

[image: cord-reel]

I'd like to think that a 100-ft extension cable with a pretty good gauge (12) would act as a substitute for a 50-ft and even for a 25-ft cable. But after winding on such a cord reel, one end will be inaccessible, and so even to use it as just a 25-ft extension, I'd have to unwind the whole thing out. Is that right?

I saw suggestions online to buy a specialized reel that picks up the extension cable from its centerpoint. That would solve the problem, but it would also introduce a stress point through excessive bending. Yet another suggestion online is to avoid a reel altogether and use a piece of wood, though I'd really rather not spend half a day fabricating something like this myself.

Comment: The cord reels that I have used had a provision to let the inner end of the extension cord (inner in terms of the end wound up first on the reel) stick out the side at the center hole. That way the business end was always accessible no matter how much you chose to unwind. The reel pictured in your posting may not support that feature.

Comment: If you need a 100' cord, by all means buy it. Having said that, you'd probably pay about the same for 2-50' cords and have way better manageability. Harbor Fright sells cheap and cheery cord reels that probably hold a 100' for about 10 bucks that will allow one end of the cord to stick out of the bottom of the roll.

Comment: I have a reel with built in female sockets on the reel, and a male plug that reels out.  It had a warning label saying the cord must be fully extended before using to avoid overheating.  I imagine your cord-on-reel would have the same issue.  You're not _supposed_ to be able to use the cord when it's partially reeled.

Comment: I have one of those reels designed to grip the cord at the center, and it is molded to not bend the cord sharply anywhere. The only downside is that I have to place the reel halfway between the outlet and the load.

Comment: I have been told by an EE that one shouldn't use a rolled extension cord, but I'm not sure he made the jump from theory to real world. In a practical sense, unrolling the whole thing will show you if there's any damage to the cord.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate having just looked up 10 gauge cords to respond to a comment about them by Tester101, you'd pay $198 for two of those from HD and only $140 for a single 100 foot. Wasn't looking at 12Ga.

Comment: @Ecnerwal -- Haven't looked seriously at cords in a while, but a glance at HF showed 50', AWG12 for $40 and 100' AWG12 for $72. I assumed (unsafe at any speed, I know) that the prices would scale at similar rates elsewhere. Before anyone sends the squad to take care of me, I need to note that HF extension cords have a poor reputation in some quarters (impure copper; smaller than advertised conductors, probably poor UV resistance).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those cord reels are very useful.  You'll need a BIG one to hold a 100' 12 gauge though.  If you leave 6" or so hanging out one of the big holes on the side, you can wrap it with the end accessible.

I wrap these with the female end on the spool, so you plug it in first and walk to where you're working.  I guess it works OK either way.

They make cord reels with receptacles on the spool ...

[image]

and those work great except when you're working on a ladder.  Sometimes the cord on the tool isn't long enough to reach this thing on the ground.

When you're working on a ladder it's nice to be able to pull some slack off either end.  This is a pretty good way to go:

[image: bucket cord storage]

That's from [a tip sent into Fine Homebuilding](http://www.finehomebuilding.com/how-to/tips/extension-cord-garage.aspx?nterms=127134,65676).

The Cordwiz Pro

[image: Cordwiz Pro]

does the same thing as the bucket trick, if you'd rather not do it homemade.

One other thing to get if you're shopping, a portable GFCI

[image: portable gfci]

Comment: Great summary. Thanks. Could you suggest a keyword for "This thing" that "does the same thing as the bucket trick, if [I]'d rather not do it homemade." so I can search for it?

Comment: @Calaf, I'll edit the answer - It's called the Cordwiz or Cordwiz Pro.

Answer (score 1):

In point of fact you are not supposed to use an extension cord without unreeling the whole thing, due to potential heat buildup. The not-a-liability-lawer approach actually pays attention to the load on the end when making that decision in practice - if running a heavy load or a continuous moderate load, don't leave it rolled up.

There are a variety of approaches to make the inner end reachable, such as clipping it to the side of the reel. If it takes you half a day to make a wood version, you are overthinking it or working remarkably slowly.

Comment: Well, after adding the time needed to select an appropriate router (which is necessary for this project, and I don't own one yet) and to learn to use it, it's probably going to be even more than half a day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend learning how to "flip-coil". It's kinder to the cable than most of these alternatives (especially important with more expensive and more fragile wiring like sound reinforcement), it pays out without tangling, and once you learn it you'll find it useful for everything frome rope to hoses. Easier ti demonstrate than describe, but if you can't find someone to teach you it's not hard to find vids and/or diagrams on the web.